# How do you create 10 discrete number combinations for a lottery?

Tags: probability, lotteries

In the lottery I participate in, the odds of winning the jackpot has been stated as being 1:5.4 million per row. Each coupon you hand in has 10 rows, where each row is a combination of 7 numbers out of the range 1 to 34.

The way I see it, if you chose the same combination 10 times, your odds are essentially 1:5.4 million, but if you choose 10 discrete combinations, your odds are essentially 1:540.000 instead.

So my question is, how do you select 10 combinations that are discrete enough to count as 10 unique combinations to maximize your odds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the lottery is fair then all results are equally likely.  Just pick any $10$ different ones.

Suppose that the game is throwing a fair die and you can bet on any two numbers.  Do you expect that some pairs are better than others?  Or would $1$ and $2$ be just as likely as any other?

You know that there are approximately $5.4$ million possibilities.  So, just label each result with a number from $1$ to $5379616$.  Each of these labels will be equally likely.  Now, do you feel the need to pick the $10$ by any rule or just pick any $10$?

The way that the result is generated is just mystique.  In reality, it is just a way to generate a random number from $1$ to $5379616$.

One non-mathematical tip is: don't pick obvious patterns and avoid numbers that might appear in dates.  These aren't any less likely to win but it is more likely that someone else has picked them and you would need to share the prize.

Another tip: don't play at all.  In most places, it is easy to calculate the expected return as the numbers of tickets sold and the prize fund are usually published.  50% is quite good for a lottery.  If this data is not published then definitely stay away.

If you must gamble then you might get much better value (less negative) elsewhere e.g. a casino.

Comment: Casinos are not legal here, the national lottery is the only legal form of gambling in Norway. I also already calculated the returns, and the average return on 50 NOK is about 25 NOK for the main lottery, and around 10 for all the other lottery forms.


I don't expect to win big ever though, I'm just playing for the fun of it :)

Comment: I added some further explanation.  It is odd that some governments ban many or all forms of gambling but then run one option themselves.  One rule for . . .  Gambling on the lottery can be just as addictive as any other form.

Comment: The first line is the important one.  There is nothing worse in picking two lines that have nine numbers in common and disagree on just one number than picking two lines with all numbers different if all you care about is the grand prize.  If there are lower prizes for matching fewer numbers it is much harder

Comment: In this case there are prizes between 4 to 7 correct numbers, where the jackpot is only paid out on weeks where one or more person has 7 correct numbers.

I didn't consider those prizes in my average return calculations though, but either way I think this answer is good enough to answer my question.

Comment: The simplest way to calculate the average return, if you have the data, is the value of the prize versus the value of the tickets sold.  Or the value of the prize fund might even be published as a % of the ticket sales.  In ones that I have heard, 50% is typical.  So, if a ticket is 100kr, your average return is just 50kr.  Here in the UK, you can get better odds from the Football Pools (predicting results) or betting on horses.  Oddly, both of those are perceived as gambling and frowned upon while the lottery is harmless fun.  I don't see the distinction and ignore them all.

Comment: It might be worth reading up on The Gambler's Fallacy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy.  This is even encouraged here; in the lottery results show they say things such as "27 has not appeared for over a month now".  Either they are admitting that the result is not fair or they are encouraging the Gambler's Fallacy.